# Computing $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I don't understand what my teacher did here, could you please explain:

$$x_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}\cdotp\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_{n-2}}\cdotp\cdotp\cdotp\frac{x_2}{x_1}\cdotp\frac{x_1}{x_0}$$
Then she said:
$$\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}=y_n=e$$
I have no idea what it means. There is a possibility I copied it wrong.
What she did next is:
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}$$
Now, I uderstand the limit solving, but nothing before it and how the professor came to it.
$$\lim \limits _{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{n!}{n^n}}{\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1)^{n-1}}}=\lim \limits _{x \to \infty} \bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{(n-1)\cdotp\frac{-n}{-n}}=$$
$$=e^{\lim \limits _{x \to \infty}(-\frac{n-1}{n})}=e^{-1}$$
And that concludes it.

Comment: I guess you copy wrong, cause second and third formulas have not sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely some copying errors here. The point is that to go from $(n-1)!$ to $n!$, you have to multiply by $n$. (We solved the equation $(n-1)!x=n!$ for $x$.) To go from $(n-1)^{n-1}$ to $n^n$, you have to multiply by $n \left ( \frac{n}{n-1} \right )^{n-1}$. (We solved the equation $(n-1)^{n-1} y = n^n$ for $y$.)

Thus to go from $\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1)^{n-1}}$ to $\frac{n!}{n^n}$, you have to multiply by $\frac{n}{n \left ( \frac{n}{n-1} \right )^{n-1}}=\left ( \frac{n-1}{n} \right )^{n-1}=\left ( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right )^{n-1}$. It is fairly well known that this goes to $e^{-1}$ as $n \to \infty$.

So your quantity is "roughly" the geometric mean of $n$ copies of $e^{-1}$, which you expect to converge to $e^{-1}$. The rest is just justifying this convergence.

Comment: I don't quite understand the point. In what way does going from $(n-1)!$ to $n!$ or from $(n-1)^{n-1}$ to $n^n$ help us? I also don't understand the first line I wrote, what did my teacher mean by that?

Comment: @A6SE In the first line, everything except $x_n$ and $x_0$ cancels, and $x_0=1$, so you get the equality. (This is a telescoping product; a more common but very similar trick is a telescoping series.) So $x_n$ is a product of $n$ terms, each of which is approximately $e^{-1}$.